# How to shrink a Vec or String from an offset without reallocating it?

Tags: rust

Multiple structures in rust have `shrink_to` or `shrink_to_fit` methods, such as `Vec` and `String`. But apparently there's nothing like `shrink_from_to`.

###### Why would I want that?

Assume I've a XY gigabyte string or vector in memory and know the exact start and end positions of the part I am interesting in (which allocates only Z GB from `start` to `end`, somewhere in the middle). I could call `truncate` and then `shrink_from_to` effectivly freeing memory.
However I've still gigabytes of memory occupied by `[0..start]` which are of no relevance for my further processing.

###### Question

Is there any way to free this memory too without reallocating and copying the relevant parts there?

Comment: Your best bet is a combination of `truncate` and `split_off`.

Comment: `shrink_X()` methods do allocate.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Can't the `GlobalAlloc` delegate his allocation to [shrink_in_place](https://docs.rs/rustc-std-workspace-std/1.0.1/std/alloc/trait.Alloc.html#method.shrink_in_place)?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `shrink_to_fit` does reallocate by copying into a smaller buffer and freeing the old buffer. Your best bet is probably just converting the slice you care about into an owned `Vec` and then dropping the original `Vec`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let v1 = (0..1000).collect::<Vec<_>>(); // needs to be dropped
    println!("{}", v1.capacity()); // 1000
    let v2 = v1[100..150].to_owned(); // don't drop this!
    println!("{}", v2.capacity()); // 50
    drop(v1);
}
```

Comment: FWIW that's not necessarily true. Depending on the allocator and layouts (specifically the alignments of the old and new layouts), [`shrink_to_fit` may ultimately call `realloc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/alloc.rs.html#262-269), which can reallocate in-place, with no copy. Increasing the size of an allocation can similarly work in-place, depending on the allocator and alignment.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to free this memory too without reallocating and copying the relevant parts there?

Move the segment you want to keep to the start of the collection (e.g. `replace_range`, `drain`, `copy_within`, `rotate`, ...), then truncate, then shrink.

APIs like `realloc` and `mremap` work in terms of "memory blocks" (aka allocations returned by malloc/mmap), they don't work in terms of random pointers. So a hypothetical `shrink_from_to` would just be doing that under the cover, since you can't really resize allocations from both ends.